# Visualizing a text schedule using Excel and conditional formatting

Tags: microsoft-excel

Trying to set up a visual representation of a work schedule using Excel:

A column has the name of the person, 
B column is the start time (a dropdown of pre-determined times on the hour), 
C column is the end of the 10 hr shift (add 10/24 then subtract 1 if this is >=1)
D-J Calumns are "Checked" if that is a scheduled work day

The blue areas are conditional formatting whether the cell is of value "1".

If the cell is scheduled for the user, I want the cell value to be 1.  Currently my formula is such:

```
=(IF($D2="X",1,0)*IF(L$10>$B2,1,0)*IF($C2>=L$10,1,0))+(IF($J2="X",1,0)*IF($B2>$C2,1,0)*IF($B2>=L$10,1,0)*IF($C2>=L$10,1,0))
```

In Row 10, I have fractions of 1/24 increasing from left to right to compare the times to.

I'm hoping someone can look at this and see where I went wrong.  I'm close...

[image]

Thanks!

-Dave

Comment: Got it!

     =(IF($D2="X",1,0)*IF($B2<L$10,1,0)*IF($C2>=L$10,1,0))+(IF($J2="X",1,0)*IF($B2<L$10,1,0)*IF($B2>$C2,1,0))

Comment: Unless you're asking about Excel Online, your question is off-topic at Web Apps. Try [su].

Answer (score 0):

=(IF($D2="X",1,0)*IF($B2=L$10,1,0))+(IF($J2="X",1,0)*IF($C2>L$10,1,0)*IF($B2>$C2,1,0))+(IF($D2="X",1,0)*IF($B2<=L$10,1,0)*IF($B2>$C2,1,0))